# Recovering the definition of exponential matrix from the abstract definition of Lie groups.

Tags: exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am studying the exponential function of the book introduction to the smooth manifold by John Lee and the following question has arisen.

Let $\exp:\mathcal{G}\to G$ exponential map, with $G$ a Lie group and $\mathcal{G}$ its Lie Algebra. The definition of this function is $\exp(X)=\gamma(1)$ with $\gamma$ the one-parameter subgroup generated by $X$

If $\mathcal{G}=gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $G=GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

How can it be verified that this definition abstractly allows us to recover the definition of exponential matrix? i.e. Why $\exp(A)=e^{A}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}A^k$?

Comment: See Proposition 20.2 and Example 20.6 in my book.

Answer (score 2):

If$$\gamma(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(At)^n}{n!},$$then $\gamma$ is a $1$-parameter subgroup of $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ and $\gamma(1)=A$. Therefore, $\exp(A)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{n!}$.

Comment: The 1-parameter subgroup are unique, right?

Comment: Yes. More precisely, for each tangent vector $v$ at the identity element of $G$, there is one and only one $1$-parameter group $\gamma$ such that $\gamma'(0)=v$.